# Iptables Forwarding

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, iptables

Hi I'm doing forwarding on a centos 7 server over vpn to a html server but also the centos server is providing internet to other computer my question is, how I do forward some ports like 80 and 443 without mask them? and keep masquerading the rest of the internet, I would like to see in the log of the https server the real ip comes from

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.100.10
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.100.10
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.100.10/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

this is part of the iptables and works

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1287771/iptables-how-to-keep-source-ip-after-forwarding

Comment: thank you mashuptwice but i already has DNAT in the rules, i think it is in ```-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.100.10/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE```  but it hive me a really good idea  !

Comment: Done thank you ! I was masquerading everything incoming as the outgoing traffic

Comment: Yes, I saw that. You might want to add an answer describing your findings and the fix.